# Add a uneditable string at the end of the text in text form field

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add the string value at the end when the user enters the value in the text form field.I can add values as a suffix but i want to add the values very near to the text form field input.

````
TextFormField(
                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontSize: 20),
                                                keyboardType:
                                                    TextInputType.number,
                                                controller:
                                                    loanTenureController,
                                                focusNode: loanTenureFocus,
                                                cursorColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                inputFormatters: [
                                                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
                                                      RegExp("[0-9]")),
                                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                                      2)
                                                ],
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                                  labelText: S
                                                      .of(context)
                                                      .loanTenureInYears,
                                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    color: getColor(
                                                        snapshot.data,
                                                        loanTenureFocus,
                                                        "loanTenure"),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]
i want like this field
````

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

put your textfield in a form widget then:

```
 Form(
    onChanged: () {
      _textEditingController.text = _textEditingController.text + 
      suffixThatYouWant.toString() 
    }
 ),
```

Comment: idk about uneditable part but you can control the text in onChanged method if text contains exact suffix then go ahead if its not reproduce suffix again